# Setting subproject pom.xml to be ignored by parent install

Tags: maven

My parent pom modules list looks something like this:

```
<modules>
    <module>jarProject1</module>
    <module>jarProject2</module>
    <module>jarProject2</module>
    <module>warProject1</module>
    <module>warProject2</module>
</modules>
```

I would like *warProject1* and *warProject2* to be ignored when I run `mvn clean install` on the parent pom. I want install to only build jars and put them in the maven repo but not the war producing projects. Currently I do it using profiles but I have some problems related to that. I would like the parent pom to keep a comprehensive list of modules in its default modules tag and not under profiles. Is there a way to do it and how?

Comment: `--projects` is not good enough?

Comment: I was really looking for a way to do `mvn clean install` and for it to differentiate based on what is on subproject poms

Comment: What is the reason to go that way? I don't see an advantage of this idea?